# Xcode extern error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I have problem with Xcode, I am getting following error when running the code:

> ```
> Error : Expected identifier or ')'
> ```

Here is th code:

```
#import "IOKitLib.h"
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import <pthread.h>
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <sys/ptrace.h>
#import <libkern/OSAtomic.h>


static     mach_port_t masterPort = 0;

extern "C" kern_return_t io_service_open_extended
(
mach_port_t service,
task_t owningTask,
uint32_t connect_type,
NDR_record_t ndr,
io_buf_ptr_t properties,
mach_msg_type_number_t propertiesCnt,
kern_return_t *result,
mach_port_t *connection
);
```

Please help me to solve this problem and let me know where am I doing wrong. Thanks !

Comment: Which line?  What is the name of this source file?

Comment: extern "C" kern_return_t io_service_open_extended

Comment: What is the name of the file?  Is it a C++ source file?

Comment: File name : gasgauge.c

Answer (score 0):

`extern "C"` is valid in C++ only.  You can make the declaration usable in any language (C++, C or Objective-C), from a header file for example, using the `__cplusplus` guard macro:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

kern_return_t io_service_open_extended
(
mach_port_t service,
task_t owningTask,
uint32_t connect_type,
NDR_record_t ndr,
io_buf_ptr_t properties,
mach_msg_type_number_t propertiesCnt,
kern_return_t *result,
mach_port_t *connection
);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: @AhmetMahmodo No, not if put into a C++ source file.

Comment: what should i do for this ?

Comment: Change all the declarations that use `extern "C"` as per my answer.

Comment: I am use this file . I should save as this file ? (Change extension?)